# Need some help on url-rewriting (htaccess)

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need some help to rewrite my URLs. I'm stuck on a pretty simple thing but regex gives me headache.
So, my website is working on an "index.php" file at its root, this index calls the pages specified in parameters.

For example: **mywebsite/index.php?page=home**
To make it cleaner I want to only keep the parameter and add "html".

So **mywebsite/index.php?page=home** can be viewed using **mywebsite/home.html**

Here's my htaccess for now:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/([a-z0-9\-]+)\.html$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: And what exactly is not working? What does it do or doesn't it do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this,

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+).html$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: Working great !